# python matplotlib : assign cmap to make multiple color scattering plot

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to use matplotlib and seaborn to create a scatter plot. It works fine if the entire plot is only one color like below:

```
sns.regplot(x = pair[0], y = pair[1], data = d, fit_reg = False, ax = ax, x_jitter = True, scatter_kws = {'linewidths':0, 's':2, 'color':'r'})
```

However, if I need the color of each data point depends on the value in `col` like:

```
col = pandas_df.prediction.map({0: [1,0,0], 1:[0,1,0]})
sns.regplot(x = pair[0], y = pair[1], data = d, fit_reg = False, ax = ax, x_jitter = True, scatter_kws = {'linewidths':0, 's':2, 'cmap':"RGB", 'color':col})
```

where pandas_df is a pandas dataframe, so `col` is a series of RGB point like:

```
[1,0,0]
[0,1,0]
[1,0,0]
[0,1,0]
   :
   :
```

Then I got the errors:

```
IndexErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-e17a2dbdd639> in <module>()
     15     #print dtype(col)
     16     d.plot.scatter(*pair, ax=ax, c=col, linewidths=0, s=2, alpha = 0.7)
---> 17     sns.regplot(x = pair[0], y = pair[1], data = d, fit_reg = False, ax = ax, x_jitter = True,                 scatter_kws = {'linewidths':0, 's':2, 'cmap':"RGB", 'color':col})
     18 
     19 fig.tight_layout()

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/seaborn/linearmodels.pyc in regplot(x, y, data, x_estimator, x_bins, x_ci, scatter, fit_reg, ci, n_boot, units, order, logistic, lowess, robust, logx, x_partial, y_partial, truncate, dropna, x_jitter, y_jitter, label, color, marker, scatter_kws, line_kws, ax)
    777     scatter_kws["marker"] = marker
    778     line_kws = {} if line_kws is None else copy.copy(line_kws)
--> 779     plotter.plot(ax, scatter_kws, line_kws)
    780     return ax
    781 

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/seaborn/linearmodels.pyc in plot(self, ax, scatter_kws, line_kws)
    328         # Draw the constituent plots
    329         if self.scatter:
--> 330             self.scatterplot(ax, scatter_kws)
    331         if self.fit_reg:
    332             self.lineplot(ax, line_kws)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/seaborn/linearmodels.pyc in scatterplot(self, ax, kws)
    353             kws.setdefault("linewidths", lw)
    354 
--> 355             if not hasattr(kws['color'], 'shape') or kws['color'].shape[1] < 4:
    356                 kws.setdefault("alpha", .8)
    357 

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

What did I do wrong in assigning color and cmap in this case? Thanks!

Comment: When you say `col` is a series of RGB, do you mean literally a Pandas `Series` object?

Comment: @mwaskom: The col is derived like below: col = pandas_df.prediction.map({0: [1,0,0], 1:[0,1,0]})   ,where pandas_df is a Pandas data frame, and the pandas_df.prediction is a column having only two values: 0 or 1. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this problem myself, with code that worked a year ago.  (I might have switched from Python 2 to Python 3, which might explain the error.)

## Reiteration

I dug into the code a bit, and as you noted, the error is at

```
--> 355             if not hasattr(kws['color'], 'shape') or kws['color'].shape[1] < 4:
356                 kws.setdefault("alpha", .8)
357 

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

If you look at what is happening here, whatever you pass into the `'color'` keyword (specifically `'color':col` in your case) needs ***both*** of the following features:

- It needs to **not** have a `shape` attribute
- But if I **does** have a `shape` attribute, that attribute must have at least 2 dimensions.

## The Root Problem

Well, there is the problem: a *pandas* `Series` or a *numpy* `ndarray` (or several other data structures, I'm guessing), have a `shape` attribute that can have only 1 dimension.

E.g., when I ran across the problem, I had something like the following:

```
col.shape

(2506,)
```

This means that my `col` variable (in my case, a *pandas* `Series` object), **both** has a `shape` **and** the shape has only 1 dimension.

It was not obvious to me how to fix this.  I tried to just force my *pandas* `Series` into a `list`, but that didn't fix things.  I tried to just pass a 2D *pandas* `DataFrame`, where each column was identical, but that didn't fix it.

## Potential Fix (for those who cannot be deterred)

In looking through the [source code](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/blame/master/seaborn/linearmodels.py#L355), it was not obvious to me how I could fix things. The *right* fix, it would seem, might be to add another check in line 355 that looked something like this:

```
355             if not hasattr(kws['color'], 'shape') or len(kws['color'].shape) < 2 or kws['color'].shape[1] < 4:
```

But I didn't have the energy (or time) to go through the hassle of forking the source and submitting the fix. :(

Comment: By the way, the problem is due to **Seaborn** code, not MatPlotLib code. You might want to change the title of your problem.